# How to get the JSON values of one specific item in my Web-project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dom, xmlhttprequest

I am facing a very frustrating problem. First of all, here are my files and I tried my best to reduce them to a minimum so the bug is still there:

server.js: Here I make 2 GET requests. The first one takes a specific ID from one sneaker and it successfully responds with the json values (so this works fine). The second GET request sets a path, on which a html file is being loaded. (This also works up until here)

```
app.get('/sneaker/id=:ID', function (req, res) {
  const id = req.params.ID;
  const exists = id in sneakers;
  res.json(Object.values(sneakers[id]));
});

app.get('/id=:ID', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"files","HTML","sneakerDetails.html")); 
});
```

details.js: Now here the problem starts: When I make an xhr request, I get the error that the "sneaker" in "sneaker.ID" is not defined. So my question is: How to access the JSON property that is inside the if statement and set it into the xhr Get request?

```
window.onload = function () {
loadData();
};


function loadData() {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      const sneaker = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      displaySneaker(sneaker);
    } else {
      ...[error handling]... 
    }
  };

  xhr.open("GET", `/sneaker/id=` + sneaker.ID);
  xhr.send();
}

function displaySneaker(sneaker) {
    const bodyElement = document.querySelector("main");

    let linkDiv = document.createElement("div")
        let link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", "/id=" + sneaker.ID);
        ...[rest of code]...
        
}
```

Now, when I set the xhr Get request to:

```
xhr.open("GET", `/sneaker/id=s001`);
```

... I do get a response in the browser with the JSON data from the ID "s001". However, when the "displaySneaker(sneaker)" function is called, the attribute of the created anchor is set to:

```
id = undefined
```

To conclude, there seems to be a problem with getting the ID of one specific item and I dont really know where the mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [Route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) documentation to check how the route parameters are defined.

- Route path: `/sneaker/:id`
- Request URL: `http://localhost:3000/sneaker/123`
- `req.params`: `{ id: 123 }`

`server.js`:

```js
app.get('/sneaker/:id', function (req, res) {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const exists = id in sneakers;
  res.json(Object.values(sneakers[id]));
});

app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"files","HTML","sneakerDetails.html")); 
});
```

`details.js`:

```js
// ...
xhr.open("GET", `/sneaker/${sneaker.ID}`);

// ...
link.setAttribute("href", "/" + sneaker.ID);
```